# How to check out a specific commit from github using svn:externals?

Tags: git, svn, github

I want to check out a specific commit of code from [github](https://github.com/) using svn:externals. It's easy to check out the trunk (discussed [here](https://kovshenin.com/2012/github-projects-as-subversion-externals/)), as shown in this svn:externals entry example:

```
https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp.git yaml-cpp
```

To check out code from a Subversion repository you would create a svn:externals entry that looks something like  (using the peg revision syntax in [red book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html)):

```
http://svn.example.com/code@<revision> code
```

This won't work, since it is not a Subversion repository I'm trying to check out. Using the accepted answer from a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539130/git-go-to-particular-revision) also does not seem to work for a SVN check out from github:

```
https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp.git@<sha1> yaml-cpp
```

Comment: Read [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.externals.html) and use PEG|Operative revisions after understanding fully externals and format of definition?

Comment: @LazyBadger: Since it is not a SVN repo I'm dealing with, the svn:externals peg revision syntax will not work.

Comment: Github have SVN-URLs for Git-repos, you **can** use PEG-revisions with it

Comment: possible duplicate of [TeamCity: Subversion VCS root with GitHub externals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894367/teamcity-subversion-vcs-root-with-github-externals)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Edit svn:externals with git svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42429730/edit-svnexternals-with-git-svn)