# Edit svn:externals with git svn

Tags: git, git-svn

Is it possible to set `svn:externals` property using `git svn propset`?

I have successfully used `git svn propset` to set the `svn:eol` property. However, for `svn:externals` I am unsure if/how it can be done because `svn:externals` is a multi-line property, and I'm not sure if/how multiple lines of the property value may be expressed on the command line.

For `svn:externals`, it would be ideal if the `git svn propset` command had an `--edit` option, which would allow the property to be edited in the text editor (similar to editing commit text or git config).

I'm using git version 2.11.1 on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Git Bash, just enclose the argument in question in quotes like

```
git svn propset svn:externals "foo
bar" baz/bam
```

Comment: I tried it, but when I did `git svn dcommit` I got errors of the form `<my-extern-name> is not a valid attribute name: src/.gitattributes:1` (one line for each extern reference). So it looks as though multi-line SVN properties just cannot be set.

Comment: I looked at the `.gitattributes` file, and it looks as though there's a small chance it might be remedied by manually editing it to add quotes around the `svn-properties=svn:externals=` value. I'll try it next time I'm wanting to update `svn:externals`. But that would be a work-around; it looks as though it's worth reporting this issue to the git mailing list.

Comment: How about adding quotes in the command like (replace `\n` by newline, comments cannot display newlines) `git svn propset svn:externals "'foo\nbar'" baz/bam` or `git svn propset svn:externals '"foo\nbar"' baz/bam`. You might even be able to do (do not replace the `\n` this time) `git svn propset svn:externals $'"foo\nbar"' baz/bam`, but I didn't try this.